# Map Objects to Database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

I've worked for some time with entity framework in a database first approach with all the fancy code generators from VS. But I have two problems with this :

1) As powerfull as it is, I am just sick of .edmx and generated code plus I want to keep the hand on my models objects. I don't want my models to be the exact reflect of my database, I just want them as I need them.

2) I no longer have access to code generation and .edmx, since I'm now working on VS Express 2013

The code first approach is not an option, since I work on an existing DB.
I have given a look to Massive and such, and I do love it, but it also reminded me how wonderful it is when many-to-many relationships are automatically managed...

So is it a way to "manually" wire objects to tables, like in Java's hibernate ?

Comment: You can do code first against an existing DB

Comment: You might want to check out NHibernate: http://nhforge.org/

Comment: I did try Code First. The simplest insert took me more than 2 second, so I decided to add a EntityTypeConfiguration to my Context, but since then I keep getting exception stating that the model has changed since the db creation. As said, I don't want my models to be the exact reflect of my database.

Comment: Have you disabled database initializer
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(null);

That should prevent the Model has changed since db creation errors